# Accessing gridview's header controls in ASP.Net, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have Gridview and the headers are having textboxs and labels, I have a search button out side of the gridview and when a user clicks on search I need to filter gridview's data by respective column's texbox values.

Comment: 'GridView' as in ASP.NET web forms or any other third party gridview? (I see you have tagged asp.net-mvc in your question)

Comment: Sorry for that, ASP.NET only.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)gridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("contorlId");
```

to specifically search within a column identify the cell by the index

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("contorlId");
```

Comment: textbox is always null. any idea?

Comment: Actually I am creating Textbox dynamically and text box Id in runtime is 'ctl00_sys_ABC_gridView1_ctl01_txtXYZ' , I am using update panel called 'ABC'

Comment: are you autogenerating the gridview? why not create the columns for the gridview so that in the designer you can place your textbox inside asp:TemplateField/HeaderTemplate

Comment: Gridview is dynamic and it will be generated as per the needs of the data source

Comment: If your controls are dynamic make sure you don't lose them on postback. If you have few controls in your header column, probably you can identify the control by type and read the value `foreach(Control c in gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    string value = ((TextBox)c).Text;
                }

            }`

Comment: I've not tried this; but there is a way to restrict the naming convention of dynamic controls in asp.net. Research on implementing `INamingContainer` marker interface (which may help you)